# How to add comment for selected text using VBA in Ms Word 2013?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created simple Template`(Open word file--> Alt + F11 --> Save file as .dtom)` to add comment to the selected text. I have save file as .dotm and place it on Start up folder `C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP`  But I am getting error of Macro Setting of Ms Word 2013. I have followed as they suggested but still can't work.

I have attached my code. Can anybody suggest if I am missing anything from code side?

Code:

```
Sub autoexe()
    Dim MainMenu As CommandBarControl
    Dim MenuItem As CommandBarPopup
    'add pop button
    MenuItem = MainMenu.Controls.Add(msoControlPopup, , , , True)
    With MenuItem
        .Caption = "Item1"
        .Visible = True
        'add simple button
        Dim simpleButton As CommandBarButton
        Dim commentText As String
        commentText = "Comment inserted successfully"
        simpleButton = MenuItem.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
        With simpleButton
            .Caption = "Show Message"
            .Visible = True
            .OnAction = "addComments(commentText)"
        End With
    End With
End Sub 


Sub addComments(ByVal cmtText As String)
    ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPageView
    Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
    If (Len(Selection) > 0) Then
        MsgBox ("inside comment")
        With Selection
            .TypeText (cmtText)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Did you `Enabled Contents` while opening the file ? Does your file has the code ?

Comment: Do you mean .dotm file extension?

Comment: @newguy Sorry but I didn't understand your question. Can you please explain? My add-in displays when Word starts. I can see button. When I click, it throw above message. I haven't set any code for `Enabled Contents`. Can you please give me example or link of that code?

Comment: @dbmitch Yes. It is `.dtom` file. I have place that file on default folder `C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP`. So, when Word starts, it takes file from default folder and display in Add-In tab.

Comment: You realize you keep spelling it as DTO-M - not DOT-M ... DOT files are document template file extensions

Comment: @dbmitch Yes, I just realize that it is `dotm` file. Thank you. Please suggest me if you have idea how to manage this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it the way you're setup right now, you can continue to use multiple global variables

```
Dim commentText As String
Dim param2 As String
Dim param3 As String

commentText = "Comment inserted successfully"
param2 = "This is parameter 2"
param3 = "This is parameter 3"
simpleButton = MenuItem.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
With simpleButton
    .Caption = "Show Message"
    .Visible = True
    .OnAction = "addComments()"
End With

Sub addComments()
    commentText = Application.CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter
    ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPageView
    Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
    If (Len(Selection) > 0) Then
        MsgBox ("inside comment")
        With Selection
            .TypeText (commentText)
        End With
    End If
    Msgbox "Param 2: " & param2
    Msgbox "Param 3: " & param3
End Sub
```

Comment: Ya, I could use this too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

> 1. click the File tab, click Options, click Trust Center, and then click Trust Center settings.
> 2. Click Macro settings.
> 3. Under Macro settings, click Enable all macros.

Can you add `C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP` to Trusted Locations?

Comment: I have done that and restarted the application. It is still not working

Comment: Can you add `C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP` to Trusted Locations?

Comment: I have found issue. It is issue related with `.OnAction = "addComments(commentText)"`. If I pass `.OnAction = "addComments()"` and `.Parameter = commentText`. Then it is working fine. It adds comment. But the issue is I want to pass 3 parameter. I have tried to pass array but not succeed. Can you suggest me how to pass 3 parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. I just change the way of passing parameter of function on button click. I don't know why it was not generating error but it was done by just one change.

Here is working code: (I still don't know how to pass multiple parameters)

```
Dim commentText As String
        commentText = "Comment inserted successfully"
        simpleButton = MenuItem.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
        With simpleButton
            .Caption = "Show Message"
            .Visible = True
            .OnAction = "addComments()"
            .Parameter = commentText 
        End With

Sub addComments()
    Dim commentText As String
    commentText = Application.CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter
    ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPageView
    Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
    If (Len(Selection) > 0) Then
        MsgBox ("inside comment")
        With Selection
            .TypeText (commentText)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't look like you even need to use .Parameter - commentText is just being retrieved in addComments from your global module variable.